# How do assign a new folder for scripts that Autokey recognizes?

Tags: autokey

I want to point autokey to a new folder containing scripts and having a hard time of it. How to get autokey to recognize the new folder and list the scripts inside the interface.  I've tried using the Preference to set scripts engine folder but can seem to make that work.

Step by step method please.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the AutoKey interface.
2. Select Folder from the 'New' drop-down
3. Navigate to where the folder you want is and highlight it. Don't go into it.
4. Click ok
5. Add scripts as needed.

[image]